# Angular JS - Notify the user if form is successfully submitted using HTML element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, forms

I am new to Angular JS and using it as the framework for my client-side JavaScript. I want to notify the user if the form is successfully submitted using HTML element (not an alert which the user requires to click "OK" in order to continue input). I used `ngShow` to show the element when the form is submitted. Below is the code of the element.

```
<p ng-model="successMessage" ng-show="isSuccess"></p>
```

However, it does not suit me because I am refreshing the page after the user submitted form successfully. As you know, this will cause the variables in `$scope` refreshed.

```
$route.reload();
```

To overcome that, I tried to not refreshing the page. Instead, I emptied all the models on my controller. Yet, it does not work well for me because I am using Angular form validation i.e. `!frmRegister.address.$pristine` and `frmRegister.address.$invalid` for all my input. Using these, I am displaying error message if the user has touched the input element, but the input content is still not right. Below is the example.

```
<div class="form-group row" ng-class="{ 'has-danger' : frmRegister.name.$invalid && !frmRegister.name.$pristine }"> 
    <label class="col-2 col-form-label">Employee Name</label>
    <div class="col-10">
        <input class="form-control" ng-class="{ 'form-control-danger' : frmRegister.name.$invalid && !frmRegister.name.$pristine }" type="text" placeholder="Enter name..." id="txtName" name="name" ng-model="name" ng-maxlength="50" required autofocus>
        <p ng-show="frmRegister.name.$invalid && !frmRegister.name.$pristine" class="form-control-feedback">Name is required.</p>
        <p ng-show="frmRegister.name.$error.maxlength" class="form-control-feedback">Name is too long.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

As I was not refreshing the page and only emptying the model, the error messages are raised due to the input has been touched.

How can I achieve to display a success message on submitted form using Angular? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: are you using `ng-route` or `ui-router`?

Comment: @couzzi I am using `ng-route`

Comment: so what I understand is, you can display your success message but it is refreshed due to `$route.reload` so your only way is to not refresh the page then you got this problem that your form is in error mode when you'll only clear it without refreshing? Did I get it right?

Comment: @JkAlombro yeah, that is right

Comment: @DarrenChristopher check my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the`$route.reload` is important, you could also tack on `?success=true` or similar to your route before the reload:

```
...

$route.updateParams({success:"true"});
$route.reload();

...
```

Inject `$routeParams` into your controller and check accordingly:

```
function Controller($scope, $routeParams) {
    if($routeParams && !!$routeParams.success){
       $scope.showSuccessMessage = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried this and it's working, however, I would like to remove the params `?success=true` when the page is refreshed. How do I do that ?

Comment: So, the params would only appears in first refresh (i.e. when `$route.reload()` is called, not when the user press refresh manually. Is it possible to achieve that ?

Answer (score 1):

`<p>` tag don't support `ng-model`, you have to use `ng-bind`. and if you successfully changed value of `isSuccess`, I think it will showup with `ng-bind`.

refer the below example about `ng-model` and `ng-bind`.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-init="data='test';iSuccess=true;">
  <h3>Shown nothing by ng-model</h3>
  <p ng-model="data" ng-show="iSuccess"></p>
  <h3>Shown by ng-bind</h3>
  <p ng-bind="data" ng-show="iSuccess"></p>
  <button ng-click="iSuccess=!iSuccess">Toggle</button>
</div>
```

Comment: example is confusing

Comment: @charlietfl I just realized that, and I modified it to be easily understood. Hope I have made it clearly enough.

Comment: Thank you! I just realized that, it would be helpful to know it! That is not the issue however.

Answer (score 0):

Well, without reloading, 
you can clear your form through this code during submit.

```
    $scope.yourFormModel = {};

    $scope.yourFormName.$setPristine(true);
    $scope.yourFormName.$setUntouched(true);
```

It will clear your form like it is untouched without refreshing the page.

Also, in your success message, use this code instead

```
<div ng-show="isSuccess">
      {{successMessage}}
</div>
```